# How to print specific value from dict#2 when all the keys match exact from dict#1

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code I have keys in dictionary(concepts). When ran, the input that matches the keys in (concepts) prints the matching values from dictionary(files). Now I'm trying to print at the bottom of the current output, the value from dictionary(files) that matches the exact values entered at the input. In this case, if you enter "Machine Learning Game" you'll get -

Enter Concept Idea: Machine Learning Games
file0004.txt
file0009.txt
file0009.txt
file0009.txt
file0004.txt
file0008.txt
file0004.txt
file0009.txt
file0004.txt
file0009.txt
file0004.txt
file0008.txt
http://file0001.txt
file0002.txt
file0004.txt
file0003.txt
file0003.txt
file0008.txt

However, files0008.txt is the only value that matched those exact specific keys present in dictionary(concept) - ((number "8")) in dictionary(concept) values. I want that one value called or any exact values (there could be more than one matching exact value) and list it below the other individual outputs. Something like -

Unique Value Output: file0008.txt

========================= CODE ==========================

```
def concept(phrase):

    # split var(phrase) at spaces and assign to var(words)
    words = phrase.split()

    # use this to list python file titles and links to open them
    files    = {1:"http://file0001.txt",
                2:"file0002.txt",
                3:"file0003.txt",
                4:"file0004.txt",
                5:"file0005.txt",
                6:"file0006.txt",
                7:"file0007.txt",    
                8:"file0008.txt",
                9:"file0009.txt"}

    # change keys to searchable simple keyword phrases. 
    concepts = {'GAMES':[1,2,4,3,3,8],
                'BLACKJACK':[5,3,5,3,5],
                'MACHINE':[4,9,9,9,4,8],
                'DATABASE':[5,3,3,3,5],
                'LEARNING':[4,9,4,9,4,8]}

    # iterate through all var(words) found in var(word)
    for word in words:
    # convert to uppercase, search var(word) in dict 'concepts', if not found return not found"
        if word.upper() not in concepts:
            print("\n'{}':Not Found in Database \n" .format(word)) not in concepts
        else:
    # for matching keys in dict 'concept' list values in dict 'files'
            for pattern in concepts[word.upper()]:
                print(files[pattern])

# return input box at end of query        
while True:
    concept(input("Enter Concept Idea: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your thinking, what you want is for the concept() function to print only the name of a file if all of the words in a phrase are associated with that file, and you want it to print all of those.

If so, using **sets** instead of **lists** would make a lot of sense. By taking the *intersection of two sets*, you end up with a set that has only the elements that are in both sets.

Apart from some spacing issues, there appear to be two mistakes in your thinking: not only file 8 matches, file 4 also matches; and you wrote 'Machine Learning Game', but you probably meant 'Machine Learning Games'.

Following the pattern of your script, but using sets instead of lists:

```
def concept(phrase):
    words = phrase.upper().split()

    files = {
        1:"http://file0001.txt",
        2:"file0002.txt",
        3:"file0003.txt",
        4:"file0004.txt",
        5:"file0005.txt",
        6:"file0006.txt",
        7:"file0007.txt",
        8:"file0008.txt",
        9:"file0009.txt"
    }

    concepts = {
        'GAMES': {1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 8},
        'BLACKJACK': {5, 3, 5, 3, 5},
        'MACHINE': {4, 9, 9, 9, 4, 8},
        'DATABASE': {5, 3, 3, 3, 5},
        'LEARNING': {4, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8}
    }

    # start with all files
    matching_files = set(files.keys())
    for word in words:
        if word in concepts:
            matching_files = matching_files & concepts[word]

    # print the resulting files
    for match in matching_files:
        print(files[match])


while True:
    concept(input("Enter Concept Idea: "))
```